Symmetric DS virtual column
How I can create a virtual column on EXTRACT phase and use as placeholder on LOAD phase?
I need get a value using lookup when the data is collected on source table and use on expression on the target table as placeholder.

What is a virtual column? What does it mean to use it as a placeholder on LOAD phase?

In your load transform, just leave the source column empty and add a target column. You should not need a virtual column as a placeholder.
